# convert byte array to a pointer with problem of endian

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, type-conversion, endianness

I should read data from a pcap file to an array, and then convert it to a struct pointer.

and there is a problem of endian.

there is my code

```
#include "stdio.h"

#pragma pack(1)
struct header
{
    unsigned char len:4;
    unsigned char version:4;

    unsigned short pkg_len;
    unsigned short pkg_flag;
};

int main()
{
    // assume i read 5 bytes from  a file into array a.
    unsigned char a [] = {0x45, 0xff, 0x08, 0xee, 0x09};
    header *i = (header *)&a;

    printf("%02hx %02hx %02hx %02hx\n", i->version, i->len, i->pkg_len, i->pkg_flag);
    return 0;
}
```

it printed :

```
 04 05 08ff 09ee
```

however, what i want is :

```
04 05 ff08 ee09
```

what should i do ? thank you very much!

Comment: What is your real problem? Why can't you just do it like `header i[]={{4,5,0xff08,0xee09}}`?

Comment: The order of bit fields is not guaranteed. You are better off using manual bit shifting so you are in more control which bits are used and how. Also, `%x` expects an `unsigned int` as input by default, so you need to cast your values when passing them to `printf`. In the case of the `unsigned short` fields, you can use `%hx` without casting.

Comment: because the array a was read from a file that can not change. what i can do is read it to an array and convert it to a struct pointer.

Comment: Can you modify the order of fields in `header` struct? Endianness of `short` fields may be solved with `htons`, but there's no built-in function to swap order within a single byte. Anyway, that would be a lot implementation and device specific, so don't expect any portability.

Answer (score 1):

The x86 uses little-endian byte order. So, you get correct result.
If you want to get high-endian result (imho, you want that), you might change each field with 'htons' function: it change host order to network (high-endian) order.

Answer (score 1):

thank you all.

the final code is like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define _UNIX
//#define WIN32

#ifdef _UNIX
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#endif

const int data4test = 1;
#define is_bigendian() ((*(char *)&data4test) == 0 )


#pragma pack(1)
struct ip_header
{
    unsigned char len:4;
    unsigned char version:4;

    unsigned short pkg_len;
    unsigned short pkg_flag;
};

int main()
{
    if (is_bigendian())
        printf("big endian \n");
    else
        printf("little endian \n");

    unsigned char a [] = {0x45, 0xff, 0x08, 0xee, 0x09};
    ip_header *i = (ip_header *)&a;

    printf("%02hx %02hx %04hx %04hx\n", i->version, i->len, htons(i->pkg_len), htons(i->pkg_flag));
    return 0;
}
```

I have not find a better way to resolve this problem.